# I'm unable to clear the form input values in the newly opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

In **First Line of code**, am opening a URL which loads a form.

```
var w = window.open(url);
```

In **Second Line of code**, am trying to erase all the input values of the 
     form in the newly opened window.

```
w.window.jQuery("#employer").find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val(' ')
```

In **Third Line of code**, am trying to print the form whose input values 
     have been erased.

```
w.window.print();
```

Comment: I don't think you can print something that does not exist anymore - why are you not able to save a copy of values to a local variable, print those, and then reset the form?

Answer (score 0):

Using `w.window.jQuery()` doesn't make it search the document in `w.window()`. You need to pass that explicitly as an argument to `jQuery`:

```
jQuery("#employer", w.document).find(('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea').val(' ');
```

Note that this will only work if the URL of the window is the same as the original page.